# Vite 5 'define' constants in vite.config.js not getting replaced

Tags: reactjs, vite

Relevant Vite docs:

- [main docs page for define in vite config](https://vitejs.dev/config/#using-environment-variables-in-config)
- [migrating from Vite 4](https://vitejs.dev/guide/migration.html#rework-define-and-import-meta-env-replacement-strategy)

My vite.config.js contains the below define statement:

```
  define: {
      __DEFINE_BUILD_TIMESTAMP__: JSON.stringify((new Date()).toISOString()),
  }
```

But the `__DEFINE_BUILD_TIMESTAMP__` string is not getting replaced. I have tried 3 strategies to get this to work:

```
const definedString1 = '__DEFINE_BUILD_TIMESTAMP__'
const definedString2 = globalThis.__DEFINE_BUILD_TIMESTAMP__
const definedString3 = import.meta.env.__DEFINE_BUILD_TIMESTAMP__

console.log('define value1', definedString1)
console.log('define value2', definedString2)
console.log('define value3', definedString3)
```

Strategy 2 works in dev mode (`vite serve --mode test`). Strategies 1 and 3 work neither in dev mode nor in  prod (`vite build`).

Simply writing `const definedString0 = __DEFINE_BUILD_TIMESTAMP__` causes a Javascript syntax error and fails to run or build.

Console in PROD:

```
define value1 __DEFINE_BUILD_TIMESTAMP__
define value2 undefined
define value3 undefined
```

Console in DEV:

```
define value1 __DEFINE_BUILD_TIMESTAMP__
define value2 2023-12-06T03:16:30.645Z
define value3 undefined
```

Any help to find one way that works in PROD would be greatly appreciated.